# Converting monthly intervals into weeks in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I've been wrapping my head around this question. So my task is to convert the data from a monthly basis to a weekly basis (Sunday to Sat would be each week). The data looks like this:

| Name | Meal | Food | date from | date to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Albert | lunch | apple | 30/05/2021 | 26/06/2021 |
| Lucas | dinner | banana | 30/05/2021 | 26/06/2021 |
| John | lunch | grape | 30/05/2021 | 26/06/2021 |

The Weekly buckets would look like this:

| Name | Meal | Food | date from | date to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Albert | lunch | apple | 1/06/2021 | 5/06/2021 |
| Albert | lunch | apple | 6/06/2021 | 12/06/2021 |
| Albert | lunch | apple | 13/06/2021 | 19/06/2021 |
| Albert | lunch | apple | 20/06/2021 | 26/06/2021 |
| Lucas | dinner | banana | 1/06/2021 | 5/06/2021 |
| Lucas | dinner | banana | 6/06/2021 | 12/06/2021 |
| Lucas | dinner | banana | 13/06/2021 | 19/06/2021 |
| Lucas | dinner | banana | 20/06/2021 | 26/06/2021 |
| John | lunch | grape | 1/06/2021 | 5/06/2021 |
| John | lunch | grape | 6/06/2021 | 12/06/2021 |
| John | lunch | grape | 13/06/2021 | 19/06/2021 |
| John | lunch | grape | 20/06/2021 | 26/06/2021 |

I'm lost to start, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to write a custom function for this purpose:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)

fn <- function(x, y) {
  stopifnot(is.Date(x))
  stopifnot(is.Date(y))
  
  intv <- floor(interval(x, y) / weeks(1))
  a <- x + (0:intv) * 7
  b <- a + days(6)
  a[1] <- round_date(a[1], unit = "month")
  
  
  dts <- tibble(start = a, end = b)
  dts
}
# Then we test our function with a pair of dates
fn(ymd("2021-05-30"), ymd("2021-06-26"))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  start      end       
  <date>     <date>    
1 2021-06-01 2021-06-05
2 2021-06-06 2021-06-12
3 2021-06-13 2021-06-19
4 2021-06-20 2021-06-26
```

Then we apply our function to our original data set:

```
DF %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("date"), ~ dmy(.x))) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(output = list(fn(date_from, date_to))) %>%
  unnest(output) %>%
  select(!starts_with("date"))

# A tibble: 12 x 5
   Name   Meal   Food   start      end       
   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <date>     <date>    
 1 Albert lunch  apple  2021-06-01 2021-06-05
 2 Albert lunch  apple  2021-06-06 2021-06-12
 3 Albert lunch  apple  2021-06-13 2021-06-19
 4 Albert lunch  apple  2021-06-20 2021-06-26
 5 Lucas  dinner banana 2021-06-01 2021-06-05
 6 Lucas  dinner banana 2021-06-06 2021-06-12
 7 Lucas  dinner banana 2021-06-13 2021-06-19
 8 Lucas  dinner banana 2021-06-20 2021-06-26
 9 John   lunch  grape  2021-06-01 2021-06-05
10 John   lunch  grape  2021-06-06 2021-06-12
11 John   lunch  grape  2021-06-13 2021-06-19
12 John   lunch  grape  2021-06-20 2021-06-26
```

Comment: fabulous strategy!  well done dear friend

Comment: Thank you dear friend, that's very kind of you.

Comment: Thank you dear @akrun , I've been meaning to check whether for example `lubridate` package is loaded before we go down the code chunk. I remember there was a function `requireNames` that will attach the package in case it wasn't loaded or attached, am I correct?

Comment: I couldn't find that function `requireNames`. There is a `require(lubridate)` which can install the package if not present and load it